# How to do I pull out numbers from python string?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I have to pull out my knot values from coefficient parameters produced by the statsmodel package and place it in its own column.

Below is a current sample of the pandas dataframe and below that, is the solution I'm looking for.  When one fits a piecewise linear model using the statsmodels package, the variable comes back as the `patsy` statement.  If one puts one knot, there will be two coefficients.  If the user puts two knots, three coefficients.  At the end of each variable statement there is a number inside brackets.  If that number = `[0]`, then I need the value in the new column to say `0`.  If the number is `[1]`, then I need the value in the new column to the first value in the `knots= []` part of the string.  If the number is `[2]`, then I need the 2nd number in the `knots=[]` statement to pulled out and so on.  I've tried the online helper tools but I have not made any breakthroughs.

```
import pandas as pd
#current

dict = {'index': ['bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[0]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[1]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[2]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(driver_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[25])[0]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(driver_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[25])[1]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(length_ft_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[32])[0]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(length_ft_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[32])[0]']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)

df1

# Solution

dict2 = {'index': ['bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[0]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[1]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[2]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(driver_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[0]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(driver_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[1]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(length_ft_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[32])[0]'
        ,'bs(np.clip(length_ft_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[32])[0]'],
       'desired_1': [0,10,25,0,25,0,32]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2)
df2
```

Comment: It seems like your strings contain expressions. Why don't you run them directly, or evaluate them?

Comment: the package does provide the coefficients. You should look int that. Or do you need a regex solution? of which i do not recomend

Comment: Hi @Onyambu. I need to pull them out so I can use those to join another table of discrete ages.  This will allow me to join with the correct coefficient according to age.

Comment: Did the answer I provide not solve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

def pull_number_and_index(input_string):
    patt = r'.*\[(\d)\]$'
    l_idx = int(re.sub(patt, r'\g<1>', input_string))
    l_patt = r'.*knots=\[(.*)\]\).*'
    l_str = re.sub(l_patt, r'\g<1>', input_string)
    knots_list = list(l_str.split(','))
    if l_idx == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return knots_list[l_idx-1]

df1['desired1'] = df1['index'].apply(pull_number_and_index)
```

The regex is a little weird, `patt` matches the last number in brackets in a capturing group, extracts that and converts it to an int.

`l_patt` matches the list following `knots=` in a capturing group, extracts it using `re.sub`. The resulting string is converted to a list with `str.split`.

Then the comparison is pretty straight foward.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
 df1.assign(desired1 = df1['index'].str.replace('.*=.','([0, ').apply(eval))
Out: 
                                               index  desired1
0  bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degr...         0
1  bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degr...        10
2  bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degr...        25
3  bs(np.clip(driver_age_model, 0, np.inf), degre...         0
4  bs(np.clip(driver_age_model, 0, np.inf), degre...        25
5  bs(np.clip(length_ft_model, 0, np.inf), degree...         0
6  bs(np.clip(length_ft_model, 0, np.inf), degree...         0
```

though, i do not recommend `eval`, you should otherwise use `ast.literal_eval`